# Validating sqlalchemy relationships

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a model like this:

```
class Widget(Base):
    obj_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("obj.id"))
    obj = db.relationship("Obj", back_populates="widgets")

    @validates("obj_id")
    def validate_obj_id(self, key, obj_id):
        return obj_id


    @validates("obj")
    def validate_obj(self, key, obj):
        return obj

class Obj(Base):
    widgets = db.relationship("Widget", back_populates="obj")
```

If I have code like so:

```
widget = Widget(obj_id=5)
```

`validate_obj_id` will fire, but `validate_obj` will not. Short of looking up `obj_id` in `validate_obj_id` and passing the object to `validate_obj`, is there a way for me to validate both fields with one function?

Comment: Unless performance is a concern, I personally prefer to always operate on the relationship instead of the foreign key, precisely because of the trickiness of dealing with two fields that affect the same column in the database but are separately managed in Python.

Comment: That's a good point. I'm trying to implement this partially including some legacy code that does some weird stuff, and I am not sure I want to go through and update every obj_id setting to obj.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is not a way to validate a relationship object that is assigned via its foreign key.

---

*Original Answer*

*As commented below, this answer is not correct. I can only assume I read the question wrong 5 years ago. This is no better than using `@validates` and isn't fired when the primary key is assigned to.*

You can use the 'set' event:

```
from sqlalchemy import event

@event.listens_for(Widget.obj, 'set', retval=True)
def validate_obj(target, value, oldvalue, initiator):
    print('event fired for validate_obj')
    return value
```

Comment: `@validates` is implemented, under the hood, as `@event.listens_for(..., 'set', raw=True, retval=True)` (plus a few more attribute events, `append` and `bulk_set`. The event is still not called for the relationship when only the FK is set.